# making a background image dynamic in wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, background-image

I am trying to get my background image dynamic in wordpress. My goal is to have the user to be able to change the background image through wordpress dashboard.
I am using Advanced Custom Field plugin.

I've read through Advanced Custom Field website but couldn't find anything on background images on it.

Sample code will be helpful.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ACF does not provide separate field for the background image but you can use the simple image filed and use it to set your background image.

for that define an image field from ACF menu. and paste this code in your page where you want to put the background image

```
<div style="background-image: url(<?php echo get_field('background'); ?>);"><div>
```

as you can see you can use css property **background-image** to set the background image here it will fetch the image stored in 'background' field and put it as an background image.

**PS:-** you have to replace fieldname 'background' with your field name.

Answer (score 0):

you can output dynamic styles in the header of your page by using the wp_head hook. here is an example (add this in your functions.php):

```
function my_inline_styles() {
    $body_bg_image="/wp-content/uploads/myimg.jpg"; //here you would get your value from ACF
    ?>
<!-- start my dynamic styles-->
<style type="text/css">
    body {background-image: url('<?= $body_bg_image ?>')};
</style>
<!-- end my dynamic styles-->
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_head', 'my_inline_styles');
```

i would recommend sticking them into the header instead of the footer, to ensure early loading of these styles.

Comment: how will this work for specific pages??  adding style rule for every single page in function.php is not what i would recommend.

Comment: @Darshkhakhkhar i was assuming, the OP is referring to setting the background image on theme level. ("change through wordpress dashboard"). but that may very well be wrong.
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/options-page/

Comment: yes i know about the option pages but adding style rule from function.php its still not the best practice instead you can use inline style with the option pages also as i have mentioned in my answer, it will work in both ways. as the body tag usually be in the header file so it will be included in every page.

Comment: @Darshkhakhkhar many themes and plugins output dynamically generated css in the header. i think it's not better or worse than outputting inline style-tags.

Comment: yes plugin devs do that because they dont have access to the theme template files. while you have total access of your theme then i suggest must not make it complicated. it just an inline style so better to put it as inline style rather then putting it in header. and as i said it will only work for the common tags like body, not page specific..